# SVG element does not move if I edit x and y values

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an SVG element like so:

```
<path
            id="selectedBusiness"
            fill="pink"
            width="32.556255"
            height="32.556255"
            x="25.221872"
            y="70.22187"
            ry="6.9823961"
            d="m 32.204268,70.22187 h 18.591464 c 3.868247,0 6.982396,3.114149 6.982396,6.982397 V 95.79573 c 0,3.868247 -3.114149,6.9824 -6.982396,6.9824 H 32.204268 c -3.868247,0 -6.982396,-3.114153 -6.982396,-6.9824 V 77.204267 c 0,-3.868248 3.114149,-6.982397 6.982396,-6.982397 z" />
```

I have changed the x and y positioning values from the ones stated above to 50 and 90 respectively, however, although the elements tab in Chrome Dev Tools and the console both show that the x and y values have changed and are now 50 and 90, the actual element on the page does not move and is still using thee original values for x and y (25.22.... and 70.22....). I have disabled cache and tried it in firefox with no luck. Can someone please help me out?
Thanks in advance

Comment: x, y, width, height attributes are not relevaznt for <path>, use transform instead

Comment: @Michael How can I use ttransform by specifying the x and y positions rather than adding on to the current positions?

Comment: <path d="your original path" transform="translate(x,y)" />

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't give a x, y, width, height attributes to the path. If you need to change the size and the position of your path you can wrap it in a symbol with a `viewBox` attribute and use the symbol with a `<use>` element. Then you can give a size and a position to the `<use>`

```html
<svg>
<symbol id="theSymbol" viewBox="25 70 33 33">
<path id="selectedBusiness" fill="pink"
            d="m 32.204268,70.22187 h 18.591464 c 3.868247,0 6.982396,3.114149 6.982396,6.982397 V 95.79573 c 0,3.868247 -3.114149,6.9824 -6.982396,6.9824 H 32.204268 c -3.868247,0 -6.982396,-3.114153 -6.982396,-6.9824 V 77.204267 c 0,-3.868248 3.114149,-6.982397 6.982396,-6.982397 z" />
</symbol>
<use xlink:href="#theSymbol" 
        width="100"
        height="100"
        x="10"
        y="10"/>          
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you Robert Longson. I've corrected the mistake